# Why are affine varieties except points not compact in the standard topology on $C^n$ ?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am starting to learn algebraic geometry and in the notes I am reading there is the following remark:

" Over the complex numbers and with the strong topology we see that $A^n$ and affine varieties (except for points) are not compact. " 
(The strong topology seems to be the standard topology in this text.)

Why is that true ?

Comment: Dear readingframe, this is an excellent question and you are quite right to ask about this non trivial assertion: +1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are never bounded. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can see that unboundedness implies non-compactness. But since i know essentially nothing about affine varieties, i am not familiar with the fact that they are never bounded. Could you please explain why ?

Comment: Morally it's because $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed.  For example, take $x^2+y^2=1$ (whose solution set is bounded over $\mathbb{R}$). You can pick unboundedly large values for $x$ and due to algebraic closure there will always be a solution for $y$.

Comment: That is nice. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 23):

Noether's normalization theorem (Mumford, [Red book](http://books.google.fr/books/about/The_Red_Book_of_Varieties_and_Schemes.html?id=iVEQmzwjvjAC&redir_esc=y), page 42 ) says that if $X$ is a variety of dimension $n$ , there exists a finite surjective morphism $X\to \mathbb A^n$.
Since, in the transcendental topology over  $\mathbb C$, affine space $\mathbb A^n$ is not compact for $n\geq 1$ , $X$ is not compact either.

**A  comment**
Exciting as it definitely is, algebraic geometry has the drawback that many very intuitive facts, like the above, are difficult to justify without some fairly technical  tools.
I think it is the duty of a teacher to acknowledge this explicitly in an introductory course (and maybe give a reference for the student to come back to later), rather than throw  offhand remarks which might discourage a student and make him feel it is his fault that he can't find the (actually quite hard) rigorous proof.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Right now it is beyond my current reach to really understand it. But hopefully i will understand it as i learn a little more about algebraic geometry in the weeks to come.

Comment: Excellent comment.

Comment: yes, my comment was on the remark called "comment":)