# Affine Algebraic Sub Variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

A subvariety of an affine algebraic variety $V\subseteq\mathbb{C}^n$ is an affine algebraic variety $W\subseteq\mathbb{C}^n$ that is contained in $V$.

So with respect to this definition, is it true that the set $U(n)$ of all unitary matrices is not an affine algebraic subvariety of $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$?

Will be very happy to follow your comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it is not a subvariety.

One way to see it is to notice that $U(n)$ is a compact subset and that non-finite subvarieties of $\mathbb C^n$ are never compact.

Comment: Related question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/119245/3217)  @Mariano: another trick we used a non-denumerable number of times? :)

Comment: Yeah... People are going to realise sooner or later! :D

Comment: Anyway, I'll upvote your *compact* answer, Mariano ...