# A complex affinie variety of dimension $\ge 1$ is never compact in the classical (Euclidean) topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, krull-dimension

> A complex affine variety $X$ of dimension at least $1$ is never compact in the classical topology.

This question is exercise 2.36b, on page 20, in [Gathmann's notes](https://agag-gathmann.math.rptu.de/class/alggeom-2021/alggeom-2021.pdf)  has already been asked before ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119245/why-are-affine-varieties-except-points-not-compact-in-the-standard-topology-on?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561746/affine-varieties-over-mathbbc-are-never-compact-in-standard-topology-unless)), but the methods used there are not really in line with the rest of Gathmann's text. I am looking for an answer, that is coherent with the rest of text.

My idea so far is the following: We note that:

> Lemma 1: Let $f$ be a complex polynomial of degree $n \ge 2$. Then $\lvert V(f) \rvert = \infty$.
>
> Proof: Fix arbitrary $a_2,\ldots,a_n \in \mathbb{C}$. By the fundamental theorem of algebra we know that $f$ splits into linear factors, and by this decomposition we see that $f(x_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ has as a root.

On the other hand we note that

> Lemma 2: Let $f$ be a complex polynomial of degree $n = 1$. Then $\lvert V(f) \rvert = 1$.

From the proof Lemma 1 we can further see that

> Lemma 3: Let $f$ be a complex polynomial of degree $n \ge 2$. Then $V(f)$ is unbounded.

However, I fail to see how to use that $X$ has dimension $\ge 1$ to apply these observations. (The abstract definition via ascending chains is a bit impractical.) Could you please give me a hint?

Edit 1: I am looking for a proof that is less heavy in terms of the machinery used than the ones in the questions linked above.

Edit 2: In an [old version of Gathmann's notes](http://150.164.25.15/%7Eisrael/Ensino/Geomalg/gathmann_main.pdf) (p.49)the exercise is stated a bit differently:

[image]

I understand that the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{A}^1$ equals the cofinite topology. But I do not see how to go on from here.

Comment: When you write degree, do you mean the number of variables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are affine varieties except points not compact in the standard topology on $C^n$ ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119245/why-are-affine-varieties-except-points-not-compact-in-the-standard-topology-on)

Comment: Please provide more detail about the type of proof you're looking for - are there specific tools you're trying to use or avoid? Without this information, your post is likely to be closed as a duplicate of one of the posts you linked.

Comment: "less heavy in terms of the machinery" is pretty vague - are there **specific** results you're trying to use or avoid?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I think you may have a gap there (or at least you need to say something different than "intersection") - any nondegenerate space curve has nontrivial intersection with a hyperplane, but the intersection with any hyperplane is a finite set of points.

Comment: @KReiser: I want to avoid the Noether normalisation and, if possible, use some basic argumentation with arguments like the ones I wrote above.

Comment: I think I found a strategy, see my second edit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the lemmas you give are usefull for this problem (unless $X$ is a hypersurface, in which case, your problem is a direct conequence of lemma 3). However, if you want a proof, you know by Noether normalisation that there exists a finite injective morphism $\iota : \mathbb{C}[X_1,\ldots,X_d] \hookrightarrow \Gamma(X,\mathbb{A}^1)$. Let $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^d$ be the morphism such that $\iota = f^*$.

$\iota$ is injective thus $f$ is dominant. It implies that $f(X)$ has a non-empty Zariski interior, which implies that it is dense for the Euclidean topology. In particular, $X$ can't be compact, or else $f(X)$ would be, and it wouldn't be dense.

Comment: This is also basically the solution from the questions that the OP links.